# How to select where number in json in mysql?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, select

I have table with participants column and I would like to select all rows contains number 2.

My code doesn't work I am not sure if I have a correct syntaxt.

```
SELECT *
FROM `test`
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(test, '2', '$participants');
```

Also how to perform select for multiple numbers? Like `SELECT * FROM test WHERE participants CONTAINS [1,2,3,4,5]`.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: `'$participants'` is **NOT** correct JSON path. Fix this error. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax

Comment: Doesn't work OR gives me errors? Do you get errors if so please show us them

Comment: *Also how to perform select for multiple numbers?* Convert list to array and use JSON_OVERLAPS().

Comment: @RiggsFolly Error in JSON path produces NULL for JSON function output and hence empty query output.

Comment: Fixed by `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(participants, '2', '$.participants');` But it returns match for `22` or `22222`